# Error accessing remote DB with sequelize via tunnel-ssh

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, ssh-tunnel

I have an EC2 Ubuntu instance on AWS with MySQL DB which I can access with the following configuration via HeidiSQL and everything works fine. My main goal is to connect to this DB through `sequelize`. I have tried to do it with npm package `tunnel-ssh` but constantly getting errors.

Settings

[image: settings]

SSH Tunnel Settings

[image: ssh tunnel settings]

AWS EC2 Instance security group settings:

[image]

[image]

Error message:

```
{ SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:139:19)
    at tryCatcher (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (G:\study\ssh-tunnel\sqlize-ssh\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
  parent:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 3306,
     fatal: true },
  original:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 3306,
     fatal: true } }
```

packages I use: `mysql2, sequelize, tunnel-ssh`

I think so far I was able to open the ssh-tunnel and run sequelize but with errors. This is the code I've written:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
const ppk = fs.readFileSync('./sample.ppk', 'utf-8');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'login', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
  }
}); 

const sshConfig = {
  user: 'ubuntu',
  host: 'sshServer',
  port: 22,
  dstHost: 'localhost',
  dstPort: 3306,
  localHost: 'localhost',
  localPort: 3307,
  privateKey: ppk
}

// initiate tunnel
tunnel(sshConfig, (error, server) => {
  if(error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('server:', server);

    sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then((db) => {
            console.log('CONNECTION ESTABLISHED! ', db);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('UNABLE TO ESTABLISH CONNECTION: ', err);
        })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by not using ssh-tunnel connection at all. I opened mysql port only for my home ip instead and created a new user with all permissions granted.
Fixed my code a bit: added a server's ip address instead of localhost. It works now.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('DBname', 'userName', 'password', {
  host: 'ec2-xx-xxx-xx-x.ap-xxxxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com',
  port: 3306,
  dialect: "mysql",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for mysql/aurora there custom Ip address if your script running locally on that EC@ then you will be able make connection.

Add one rule with anywhere access and try it. for mysql

Comment: Tried adding a rule to Outbound: (mysql/aurora tcp 3306 ::/0) but still getting the same error.

Comment: add inbound not outbound

Comment: Yes, did that but nothing changed..
My inbound configuration includes the following: SSH - TCP/22/custom(0.0.0.0/0), SSH - tcp/22/custom(::/0), MYSQL/Aurora - TCP/3306/anywhere(::/0)